give tab focus() on a component when rendering in vue
I have button icon which is a separate component. I need to give the tab focus on this element after page is rendered. I am using Composition API in Vue 3. I tried adding ref to this component but it seems not working.
here is the coding example:
<icon-button
 name="edit"
 :tooltip="$t('Change Profile Picture')"
 @click="openEmployeeProfileModal"
 size="small"
 data-test="profile-modal-trigger"
 class="prof-photo-edit-icon"
 v-if="hasEditPermission"
/>


Did you try "autofocus" attribute? " I tried adding ref" - what did you try? The question needs https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

ref="profileEditIcon" add this to icon-button and inside onmount tried to foucs
onMounted(() => {       if (profileEditIcon.value) {         profileEditIcon.value.focus();       }     });

This could work. Please, provide a way to reproduce. Also, "Did you try "autofocus" attribute?"

I tried autofoucs also. since icon-button is a seperate component i think ref and autofocus not working. I can't do modification to component also since it is main component which is used in our project all over.

When you attempt to focus this element with ref or autofocus it will do so using the root element of the component, which may or may not be focusable. If the element you're trying to focus is nested, you'd need some other strategy. A boolean prop for example, and then component code that sets focus when the prop is true. The idea you can't change the component is not a strong argument, imo. When functionality is tied conditionally to a prop, you can safely modify the component without causing any side effects elsewhere in your app where the component is used.

@Danu The question needs https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can be reproduced by others, as said. What said yoduh is a plausible explanation, but there needs to be no place for guesswork
